# How do I take all observables and consolidate them into 1 array?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I have this, right now I'm getting single values on `subscribe` but what I really want is one big array. I've tried toArray, zipAll, and a number of other things (note that the concatAll() is probably completely unecessary, but I'm not sure). How do I get from a stream of observables, to a stream of 1 observable that is an array.

```
    from(registrations)
      .pipe(
        groupBy((p) => {
          const { token, ...provider } = p;
          return Object.keys(provider)[0];
        }),
        mergeMap((group) => group.pipe(map((value) => mapper[group.key](value))).pipe(toArray())),
      )
      .pipe(concatAll())
```

Comment: What's the problem with `toArray()`. That should do exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @martin instead of one big array, each item was becoming its own array

Comment: It looks like you put `toArray()` inside `mergeMap()`. I think you'll need to make a stackblitz showing what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to reduce an observable of observables to a single observable that emits an array of each inner observable's results then [combineAll](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/combineAll) might be what you're looking for.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mkmqyv?file=index.ts) demo:

```js
import { fromEvent, interval, from, Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map, combineAll, take } from "rxjs/operators";

/*
Create an Observable that emits every second, up until count times.
*/
function createIntervalObs(count: number): Observable<any> {
  return interval(1000).pipe(
    map(out => `Obs${count}@${out}`),
    take(count)
  )
}

const outerObs$ = from([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]).pipe(
  map(num => createIntervalObs(num))
)

outerObs$.pipe(
  combineAll()
).subscribe(out => {
  console.log(out);
})
```

Output:

```
["Obs5@0", "Obs4@0", "Obs3@0", "Obs2@0", "Obs1@0"]

["Obs5@1", "Obs4@0", "Obs3@0", "Obs2@0", "Obs1@0"]

["Obs5@1", "Obs4@1", "Obs3@0", "Obs2@0", "Obs1@0"]

["Obs5@1", "Obs4@1", "Obs3@1", "Obs2@0", "Obs1@0"]

["Obs5@1", "Obs4@1", "Obs3@1", "Obs2@1", "Obs1@0"]

["Obs5@2", "Obs4@1", "Obs3@1", "Obs2@1", "Obs1@0"]

["Obs5@2", "Obs4@2", "Obs3@1", "Obs2@1", "Obs1@0"]

["Obs5@2", "Obs4@2", "Obs3@2", "Obs2@1", "Obs1@0"]

["Obs5@3", "Obs4@2", "Obs3@2", "Obs2@1", "Obs1@0"]

["Obs5@3", "Obs4@3", "Obs3@2", "Obs2@1", "Obs1@0"]

["Obs5@4", "Obs4@3", "Obs3@2", "Obs2@1", "Obs1@0"]
```